# Ошибка Android программы

Tags: java, android

Дали методичку и сказали сделать лабораторную, начинаю компилировать код, но почему-то ошибка...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ua.opu, PID: 2124
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ua.opu/ua.opu.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at ua.opu.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at ua.opu.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:15) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060057
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:252)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:139)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at ua.opu.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:15) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2124 SIG: 9
```

MainActivity:

```
    package ua.opu;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.press_me);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_text);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText("Hello, Android");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

SplashActivity:

```
    package ua.opu;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

//       if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
//
//            getSupportActionBar().hide();
////        }
        Button startNewActivityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.weather_button);

        startNewActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ua.opu">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">




        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
<!--            <intent-filter>-->
<!--                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->
<!--                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
<!--            </intent-filter>-->
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_splash.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/weather_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Узнать погоду"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.875" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash_image"
        android:layout_width="403dp"
        android:layout_height="605dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.433"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/background" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Код должен быть текстом, а не изображением. И при этом нужно показывать код того класса, где ошибка, а не какой-то любой участок.

Comment: приложите код вашего класса, и код разметки xml

Comment: Вроде все добавил

Comment: activity_main.xml покажите еще пожалуйста

Comment: <ImageView в splash_activity.xml зачем вам нужно? вы его используете?

Comment: Да использую, но меня интересует ошибка сама, я не думаю что дело в оформлении приложения

Comment: `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class ImageView` - это ваша ошибка, проблема в том что проблема с imageview, поэтому я и спрашиваю

Comment: `final TextView textView` - тут final уберите

Comment: А да... Удалил ее и все начало работать.. А что не так с ней было?

Comment: но вам ведь нужен будет imageview?

Comment: это просто лабораторка и мое право вставлять туда картинку или нет, так что думаю нет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106064/discussion-between-andrew-and-torin-21).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такую разметку для вашего файла `activity_splash.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash_image"
        android:layout_width="403dp"
        android:layout_height="605dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/background" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/weather_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Узнать погоду"
        android:layout_below="@id/splash_image"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

или такой вариант:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash_image"
        android:layout_width="403dp"
        android:layout_height="605dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/background" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/weather_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Узнать погоду"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

я думаю проблема кроется в вашей разметке. У вас там очень много чего записано, в итоге приложение не может правильно ее обработать.